# How to get the border sizes of a userform?

Tags: excel, vba, api

I have a userform (userform1) with several controls. One control is a command button which will open a second userform (userform2).

I want that userform2 opens immediately bellow the button and centered with it.

To have the same behavior regardless the system/themes definitions for Windows, I need to know the sizes of the borders of userform1.

After digging during 3 days, I used API functions GetWindowRect and GetWindowClient. With these two API routines, I can find the TOTAL sizes of the horizontal borders (upper plus lower) and of the vertical borders (left plus right), but not them individually.

For vertical borders, it is common sense that they will have the same thickness (width) — in fact, I’ve never seen a window with different left and right borders. So, the solution is to divide by 2 the total size. However, for horizontal borders this cannot be used, since the upper border is usually thicker that the lower.

Eventually, I found a workaround for the problem, but it cannot be applied always. That is, if there is a frame control inside userform1, then the API function GetWindowRect can be used to find the “absolute” coordinates of the frame, i.e., referred to the screen, not to userform1. Then, the upper border size is given by: frame.top_Absolute – (Userform1.top_Absolute - frame.top_RelativeToUserform1).

The problem of this approach is, userforms have not frame controls always. On the other hand, not all controls have a “rectangle” property; therefore, GetWindowRect cannot be used for all controls.

Question: is there a “direct” way to find the size of the borders of a userform?

Code

In an ordinary module:

```
Option Explicit

'API Declarations

#If VBA7 Then
Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" (ByVal Index As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal Index As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByRef lpRect As udtRECT) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetClientRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByRef lpRect As udtRECT) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#Else
Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" (ByVal Index As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long) As Long
Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal Index As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByRef lpRect As udtRECT) As Long
Declare Function GetClientRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByRef lpRect As udtRECT) As Long
Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If

Type udtRECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Public Type BorderSize
    TopHeight As Long
    LeftWidth As Long
    BottomHeight As Long
    RightWidth As Long
End Type

Public FormBorders As BorderSize

'To determine the sizes of the borders

Public Sub GetFormBorders(ByVal FormHandler As Long, ByVal FrameHandler As Long)

Dim rectForm As udtRECT
Dim rectFrame As udtRECT
Dim rectClientForm As udtRECT
Dim Trash As Long

Trash = GetWindowRect(FormHandler, rectForm)
Trash = GetWindowRect(FrameHandler, rectFrame)
Trash = GetClientRect(FormHandler, rectClientForm)

FormBorders.TopHeight = ConvertPixelsToPoints(rectFrame.Top - rectForm.Top, "Y") - frmFlyschGSI.fraRockProp.Top         'userform1.frame.top
FormBorders.LeftWidth = ConvertPixelsToPoints(rectFrame.Left - rectForm.Left, "X") - frmFlyschGSI.fraRockProp.Left
FormBorders.BottomHeight = ConvertPixelsToPoints(rectForm.Bottom - rectForm.Top, "Y") - FormBorders.TopHeight - _
                           ConvertPixelsToPoints(rectClientForm.Bottom - rectClientForm.Top, "Y")
FormBorders.RightWidth = ConvertPixelsToPoints(rectForm.Right - rectForm.Left, "X") - FormBorders.LeftWidth - _
                         ConvertPixelsToPoints(rectClientForm.Right - rectClientForm.Left, "X")

Debug.Print FormBorders.TopHeight, FormBorders.LeftWidth, FormBorders.BottomHeight, FormBorders.RightWidth

End Sub

'To convert pixels to points

Public Function ConvertPixelsToPoints(ByVal sngPixels As Single, ByVal sXorY As String) As Single

'Credits to: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/userforms/positioning.htm

Dim hDC As Long

hDC = GetDC(0)

If sXorY = "X" Then
    ConvertPixelsToPoints = sngPixels * (72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, 88))
End If

If sXorY = "Y" Then
    ConvertPixelsToPoints = sngPixels * (72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, 90))
End If

Call ReleaseDC(0, hDC)

End Function
```

'In the Userform code sheet:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Some code here

If Me.Visible = False Then
    Call GetFormBorders(FindWindow(vbNullString, frmFlyschGSI.Caption), frmFlyschGSI.fraRockProp.[_GethWnd])
End If

'More code here

End Sub


Private Sub cmdMiHarder_Click()

Dim FrameBorder As udtRECT
Dim Trash As Long
Dim sngTopBorder As Single
Dim sngLeftBorder As Single

'Some code here

Trash = GetWindowRect(Me.fraRockProp.[_GethWnd], FrameBorder)

sngTopBorder = ConvertPixelsToPoints(FrameBorder.Top, "Y") - (Me.Top + Me.fraRockProp.Top)
sngLeftBorder = ConvertPixelsToPoints(FrameBorder.Left, "X") - (Me.Left + Me.fraRockProp.Left)

'More code here

End Sub
```

Comment: Is [THIS](https://prnt.sc/o6sgkl) what you are trying?

Comment: Yes, something like that in run time, but with the top of userform2 "touching" the bottom of CommandButton1

Answer (score 4):

**Logic:**

1. Show Userform1 as modeless. This is required so that Userform2 can be shown as modeless
2. Show Userform2 as modeless. This is required so that Userform2 can be moved
3. Move Userform2 to the relevant position

**New Position Calculations:**

Can be much better explained with the below image

[image]

**In a Module:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

**In `Userform1` code area:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function ClientToScreen Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "Gdi32" _
(ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, _
ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const LOGPIXELSX = 88
Private Const LOGPIXELSY = 90

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Const HWND_TOP = 0
Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    RepositionForm UserForm2, CommandButton1
End Sub

Public Sub RepositionForm(f As Object, c As Object)
    Dim P As POINTAPI
    Dim meHwnd As Long, hwnd As Long

    meHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, Me.Caption)

    P.x = (c.Left - (f.Width / 4)) / PointsPerPixelX
    P.y = (c.Top + c.Height) / PointsPerPixelY

    '~~> The ClientToScreen function converts the client coordinates
    '~~> of a specified point to screen coordinates.
    ClientToScreen meHwnd, P

    UserForm2.Show vbModeless

    '~~> Get Handle of Userform2
    hwnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", "UserForm2")

    '~~> Move the form to relevant location
    SetWindowPos hwnd, HWND_TOP, P.x, P.y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE
End Sub

Private Function PointsPerPixelX() As Double
    Dim hDC As Long
    hDC = GetDC(0)
    PointsPerPixelX = 72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX)
    ReleaseDC 0, hDC
End Function

Public Function PointsPerPixelY() As Double
    Dim hDC As Long
    hDC = GetDC(0)
    PointsPerPixelY = 72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY)
    ReleaseDC 0, hDC
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Nice solution for placing userform2! Thank you.
Your code put me in the right way to find a solution for calculating the border sizes of a userform, regardless its controls: the key is the ClientToScreen API function, which replaces the “frame” used in my previous code to find a reference inside the userform. The relevant code is shown in the reply below.

Answer (score 3):

I can answer to my own question now after reading Siddharth Rout’s code. The key is to use the ClientToScreen API function to find the “screen” coordinates of the upper left corner of the client window (of the userform).

I am leaving here the code, in case someone needs to know the border sizes of a userform.

In a ordinary module:

```
Option Explicit
'
'API Declarations
'
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal Index As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByRef lpRect As udtRECT) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetClientRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByRef lpRect As udtRECT) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function ClientToScreen Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByRef lpPoint As PointAPI) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long) As Long
    Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal Index As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByRef lpRect As udtRECT) As Long
    Declare Function GetClientRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByRef lpRect As udtRECT) As Long
    Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Declare Function ClientToScreen Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnD As Long, ByRef lpPoint As PointAPI) As Long
#End If
'
Public Type udtRECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type
'
Public Type PointAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type
'
Public Type BorderSize
    TopHeight As Single
    LeftWidth As Single
    BottomHeight As Single
    RightWidth As Single
End Type
'
' To determine the sizes of the borders
'
Public Function FormBorders(ByVal FormHandler As Long) As BorderSize
'
' Credits to Siddharth Rout for the usage of ClientToScreen API function in this context.
'
    Dim rectWindow As udtRECT
    Dim rectClient As udtRECT
    Dim P As PointAPI
    Dim VerBorders As Single
    Dim HorBorders As Single
    Dim Trash As Long
'
    Trash = GetWindowRect(FormHandler, rectWindow)
    Trash = GetClientRect(FormHandler, rectClient)
'
'   Sets the upper left corner of the "client" window...
    P.x = 0
    P.y = 0
    Trash = ClientToScreen(FormHandler, P)      '...and gets its screen coordinates.
'
'   Total dimensions of the borders in points, after converting pixels to points:
    VerBorders = ConvertPixelsToPoints((rectWindow.Right - rectWindow.Left) - (rectClient.Right - rectClient.Left), "X")
    HorBorders = ConvertPixelsToPoints((rectWindow.Bottom - rectWindow.Top) - (rectClient.Bottom - rectClient.Top), "Y")
'
'   Now the individual borders, one by one, in points:
    FormBorders.TopHeight = ConvertPixelsToPoints(P.y - rectWindow.Top, "Y")
    FormBorders.BottomHeight = HorBorders - FormBorders.TopHeight
    FormBorders.LeftWidth = ConvertPixelsToPoints(P.x - rectWindow.Left, "X")
    FormBorders.RightWidth = VerBorders - FormBorders.LeftWidth
'
    Debug.Print FormBorders.TopHeight, FormBorders.LeftWidth, FormBorders.BottomHeight, FormBorders.RightWidth
'
End Function
'
'To convert pixels to points
'
Public Function ConvertPixelsToPoints(ByVal sngPixels As Single, ByVal sXorY As String) As Single
'
'Credits to: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/userforms/positioning.htm
'
    Dim hDC As Long
'
    hDC = GetDC(0)
    If sXorY = "X" Then
        ConvertPixelsToPoints = sngPixels * (72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, 88))
    End If
'
    If sXorY = "Y" Then
        ConvertPixelsToPoints = sngPixels * (72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, 90))
    End If
    Call ReleaseDC(0, hDC)
'
End Function
```

In the code sheet of the userform:

Option Explicit

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'
    Dim MeBorders As BorderSize

    MeBorders = FormBorders(FindWindow(vbNullString, Me.Caption))

    Debug.Print MeBorders.TopHeight, MeBorders.LeftWidth, MeBorders.BottomHeight, MeBorders.RightWidth

End Sub
```